# What's the correct phrase to ask "from what something is made"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

Are following phrases correct?

1) *What is it made of?*
 2) *What it is made of?*

Thanks.

Comment: (1) is normal. Another version of (1) is _What's it made out of?_  (2) is ungrammatical because subject and auxiliary must be inverted in questions.

Comment: There is a similar question on ELL that was migrated from EL&U: [Which is correct? - “Guess, what it is?” or “Guess, what is it?”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/46959/9161) that might be helpful (although it isn't an answer to this question)

Answer (score 1):

1) is correct:
What is it made of?

The other might appear as a phrase. 
Alice asked, "What is it made of?"
Bob replied, "Wood is what it is made of."